# ASP.NET GridView problem

Tags: asp.net

Well i have a gridview where i have defined the columns on my own and turned autogenerating off but now i have the problem that i cant access GridView.SelectedRow.DataItem.

As it turns out to be null now, when it had a value when auto generation was turned on..

Edit:
What i need is a way to save the ID of the row while not showing the ID to the user so if there is any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing DataItem is only properly filled when you are using DataBinding.
Are you using DataBinding?

Ok from this [url](http://forums.asp.net/t/903560.aspx):

> The GridView (and actually, all our
>   data controls) does not save data
>   items across postbacks.  This reduces
>   ViewState (if the objects are even
>   serializable) and enables garbage
>   collection to happen and clean up your
>   objects.  So, when you click the
>   button to post back, the GridView has
>   not called DataBind and therefore your
>   data item isn't there.  This is what
>   you've discovered.

Guessing you're reading the value from a postback, might just be the problem.

Try using SelectedValue, if you've setup the (primary) key for the items. 
I've always used that and it worked.
[msdn about SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedvalue(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: List<CrewBasicDataStatusDC> list = GetList();
GridView1.DataSource = list;
GridView1.DataBind();

So yes i am :P

Comment: Yes i do SelectedIndexChanged, but when i had AutoGenerateColumns turned on it worked....

Comment: Thanks alot selected value did the tick!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new hidden template column that will have a label with the ID . and in the cs file you use .FindControl on the rows.

You also have [DataKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys.aspx) property on the gridview, witch I think also does what you want